# Prevent losing data when refreshing on a different route - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, local-storage

I wanted to prevent losing state on page refresh while being on a different route path. Im curious why the first example does not work. From what i understand when app mounts first thing that gonna render is component itself and then `useEffects` run. Since i got 3 here, first fetches and saves the data to the `invoiceList` state and then next useEffect that run **should** fill localStorage key with  `invoiceList` state data. The last one obviously retrieve the data.

The second one does fill the `"invoiceData"` localStorage key with an **empty array**. Why is this happening if the `invoiceList` state already have the data after the first  `useEffect`?

The second example that i provided works. I removed second `useEffect` and set localStorage key in the first useEffect with response data that i get from fetch.

I also wonder if im doing everything correct here. Any feedback appreciated :)

**First example (not working):**

```
    import { ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
    import { Bar } from "../../components/Bar/Bar";
    import { Invoice } from "./Root.utils";
    
    type Props = {};
    
    const Root = (props: Props): ReactElement => {
      const [invoiceList, setInvoiceList] = useState<Invoice[]>([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const response = await fetch("./data.json");
          const data = await response.json();
    
          setInvoiceList(data);
        };
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem("invoiceData", JSON.stringify(invoiceList));
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setInvoiceList(
          JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("invoiceData") || "[]")
        );
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Bar />
          <Outlet context={{ invoiceList }} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Root;
```

**Second example (working):**

```
    import { ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
    import { Bar } from "../../components/Bar/Bar";
    import { Invoice } from "./Root.utils";
    
    type Props = {};
    
    const Root = (props: Props): ReactElement => {
      const [invoiceList, setInvoiceList] = useState<Invoice[]>([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const response = await fetch("./data.json");
          const data = await response.json();
    
          window.localStorage.setItem("invoiceData", JSON.stringify(data));
    
          setInvoiceList(data);
        };
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setInvoiceList(
          JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("invoiceData") || "[]")
        );
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Bar />
          <Outlet context={{ invoiceList }} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Root;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is never storing the data into the `localStorage` because the `fetch` is an asynchronous function that and you are writing basically always the empty array into your `localStorage`.

The order of execution in the first example will be:

1. `fetchData` called
2. `window.localStorage.setItem("invoiceData", JSON.stringify(invoiceList));` <- still empty array
3. `setInvoiceList(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("invoiceData") || "[]"));`
4. `response.json()` called
5. `setInvoiceList(data);` called

I would also recommend to improve your code a little like that:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
    import { Bar } from "../../components/Bar/Bar";
    import { Invoice } from "./Root.utils";
    
    const Root: React.FC = () => {
      const [invoiceList, setInvoiceList] = useState<Invoice[]>([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setInvoiceList(
          JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("invoiceData") || "[]")
        );
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const response = await fetch("./data.json");
          const data = await response.json();
    
          window.localStorage.setItem("invoiceData", JSON.stringify(data));
    
          setInvoiceList(data);
        };
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Bar />
          <Outlet context={{ invoiceList }} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Root;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Link** component from react-router and specify to={} as an object where you specify pathname as the route to go to. Then add a variable e.g. data to hold the value you want to pass on. See the example below.

Using the `<Link />` component:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/page",
    state: data // your data array of objects
  }}
>
```

Using history.push()

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/page',
    state: data // your data array of objects
})
```

Using either of the above options you can now access data on the location object as per the below in your page component.

```
render() {
  const { state } = this.props.location
  return (
    // render logic here
  )
}
```